# Why can't you run OS X on a PC?

Tags: macos, mac

When I think about it Macs and PCs have very similar hardware. For example examples Macs use Intel Core CPUs and PCs can have them too. Same with GPUs. One main difference is of course Macs run **OS X** and PCs **can't** (excluding 'hackintosh').

My question is **why**, for example, a Snow Leopard DVD will boot on a Mac but **not** on a PC?

Comment: Modern Macs are PCs.

Comment: As "PC" is an acronym for "personal computer", by definition, _all_ Macs (even as far back as the Macintosh 128k) are PCs. They are _personal_ computers. The only thing I can think of for why a machine wouldn't be a PC is if it's a shared machine or server. The only reason I can think of for why "Macs aren't PCs" is from the _Mac vs. PC_ ads Apple ran years ago showcasing how they're different than PCs because they do certain things different than Windows. But because they are _personal_ computers, Macs _are_ PCs.

Comment: I don't think @gronostaj nor the OP were interested in the terminology, and I think for the context of the question we understand "Mac" being an Apple PC and "PC" being everything else.

Comment: The term is *IBM compatible*.

Comment: @Mazura Macs *are* IBM Compatible. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, before Apple switched to Intel, that ***was*** the reason.

Now that they do use Intel-- well, I think our own [Journeyman Geek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek) has the answer:

> Oddly enough? Apple systems **check for a specific chip** and refuse to
>   run or install without it. This is called the **[system management
>   controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller)**, and in effect is a glorified fan controller amongst other
>   things. Practically speaking, this is the reason, outside of some
>   other specific things that might be different – such as video card
>   firmware for video cards and OS X specific drivers for various things
>   (sound cards come to mind) that you **can’t ‘just’ boot a vanilla copy**
>   **of OS X right on your beige box pc**. Of course, this isn’t that hard to
>   get around, which is why your average OS X hosted VM host can run OS X
>   VMs, and there are Hackintosh distros floating around.
>
> Most Hackintosh install methods these days use variations of **boot132**,
>   a bootloader that was provided when Apple was transitioning from PPC
>   to Intel with some modifications. The original bootloader was open
>   source, and built with some changes for Darwin. As an aside, there
>   have been some attempts to repackage Darwin as an open source OS.
>
> Apple supports a **limited range of hardware** you know will work.
>   Otherwise, you’re going to have to scrounge up tested hardware or hack
>   hardware into working. This is what makes running OS X on commodity
>   hardware **difficult**. The SMC is relatively trivial to get around.
>   Getting your unsupported sound chip (nothing like having your mic
>   stuck at maximum volume on a laptop to ruin your day), video adaptor,
>   and other hardware is the tricky part. If you have an AMD processor,
>   for example, the stock kernel will take one look at it and panic like
>   a mouse ran up its pants. In many cases, the solution ends up being
>   building a new kernel, with patches off Darwin source (which is FOSS)
>   and using that.
>
> **In short, the big problem isn’t the magic chip, it is OS X needing to**
>   **play nice with the entire system.**

Source: [Why is it Still so Difficult to Install OS X on PCs?](http://www.howtogeek.com/178031/why-is-it-still-so-difficult-to-install-os-x-on-pcs/)

Comment: @Nelson kinda, though the broader TL;DR is because: Apple is in the hardware business. They sell hardware. It didn't make any business sense to let the OS run on anything *but* Apple hardware.

Comment: I'm laughing too hard at myself being quoted from a quote of an answer I posted,

Comment: Just to unravel the quote layers, here's the original question with the answer that was quoted in the article being quoted here... http://superuser.com/a/679911/132466